# Is it possible to use a badge with a private Stash repository

Tags: npm, repository, bower, badge

Is it possible to use a badge with a private Stash repository? My client has some private Bower libraries and we would like to provide the consumers (developers) with a quick overview of the state of the library, just like many Github libs do in their READMEs. All I find about badges require the library to be public.

I was looking mainly through those:

- http://shields.io/
- https://badge.fury.io/

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: See this shield issue https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/647